# Не работают ajax функции

Tags: php, ajax, json

Изучаю ajax запросы, помогите побороть мое недопонимание.
Написал такой скрипт

```
<script>
function parse_links(count){

        if( !count ){

            alert('Error!');

        } else {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/engine/ajax/parser.links.php",
                data:{action: 'getdata',  count: count},
                cache: false,
            });

        }
return false;
HideLoading('');
}

function pre_parse_links(){

        ShowLoading('');
            $.ajax({
                url: "/engine/ajax/parser.links.php",
                data:{action: 'search',  url: 'http://site.com', newsid: '777'},
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {

                    if ( data.status == "ok" ) {

                        parse_links(item.count);

                    } else {

                        HideLoading('');
                        alert('Ничего не найдено!');

                    }

                }
            });
}
</script>
```

Так как мне нужен автоматический запуск без нажатий каких либо кнопок ниже этого скрипта вставил

```
<div onload="pre_parse_links()"></div>
```

Вторая функция возвращает такой массив

```
$cont = 5;
$url = "http://site.ru";
$responseArray[] = array(
                'count' => $cont,
                'url' => $url
            );

$response = $responseArray;

    if ($response){

        die(json_encode(array(
            'status' => 'ok',
            'result' => $response,
        )));

    } else {

        die(json_encode(array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'error' => '#02',
        )));

    }
```

Первая должна получить параметры count и url и автоматически обработать оставшийся php код. Косячу где-то в самом построении функций ajax. Жду вердирктов, спасибо

Comment: я не вижу, где определена переменная `items`, у которой берется `count`: `parse_links(item.count);`

Comment: "Вторая функция возвращает такой массив" - куда возвращает?

Comment: и еще: после `return false;`  происходит выход из функции, а не выполнение `HideLoading('');`

Comment: @Igor, очевидно это результат запроса

Comment: Аджакс очевидно хромат и не переносит пыль.

Comment: по этой причине и написал сюда, может подскажет кто как поправить ситуацию. а то что он не срабатывает ибо не корректно составлен и сам вижу на сайте

Comment: @DomiToriKun, откуда в коде взялась переменная `items`, у которой берется count: `parse_links(item.count);` Она нигде не объявлена.